# UITableView Dynamic update

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4

I am not sure what i m trying is the right approach?.

1) App has two tabs. In tab-2 i have UITableView.
2) App has global NSMutableArray named gData [ Singleton ]  which can be updated anytime by different part of the Application.

Now The Objective is to display gData into the UITableView.

3)  The UI has a a variable tableData used as a data source for UITableView.
4)  Have implented ViewWillAppear, and in that 
             gData is copied into tableData , and UITableView is reloaded.

This this it is fine,

1)  Now user always in the tab where UITableView is visible.

2)  somewhere in the application the global gData is updated.

3)  What i have done is implemented NSNotifition  and it is raised by module that updates gData.

4) tab-2 captured that Notification and tries to copy From gData to tableData and tries to reload the UITableView.

**WHAT IS THE ISSUE:**

1) User is in the tab-2 UITableView Visible.

2) Even thought the application reloads UITableView, it is not reflected until i touch the screen and scroll?..

IS IT POSSIBLE TO SEE DYNAMICALLY KEEPS ON UPDATING THE ROWS, AND THE USER SEE IT ?

Much appreciated the help!!..

Comment: Do you want to update UITableView content ?.  is the Contents are given in NSMutableArray ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see the implementation as if rows are stacked in the display..

Comment: aftr add new Object into NSMUtableAray set the reload data ie, [tableViewName reloadData]; It will update the tableView.

Comment: Vineesh, thx for the reply. True, but what i wanted is to see the visibility of updation in the UI. [ ie: Means i should be able to see as if stacked each rows in the table.

Comment: When  reloadData  the entire tableView will be updat.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call UITableView's "-reloadData" method ?
Or, you may send "-setNeedsDisplay"/"-setNeedsLayout" to UITableViewCell(visible cells) to update each cells ?

Comment: Yes, i am invoking -reloadData.